# The best solution (considering time complexity) for the function implementation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

A function does the following task:
For example L = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [1, 8, 6, 10, 21], [1, 4, 6, 9], [22]]; (array of arrays)

find out the index number of L such that all digit numbers in the value(sub-array) don't appear in other sub-arrays. In this example, the function would return 5 (the index of [22]) because 22 is only in this sub-array.

What could be the optimal solution in time complexity

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: What is a `digit number`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is to keep track of all the numbers you've seen so far (for example in a hashset), and process the sub-arrays one by one until you find one which matches your condition. In the worst case it's O(n) basic set operations, where n is the sum of the lengths of the subarrays of L. This is O(n) comparisons on average if you use a hashset.